# How to Configure multiple sites locally?

Tags: localhost, wamp, local

I have set up wamp locally on my machine but i want to view multiple sites locally when i need to.

So far I have entered the following code in the hosts file

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


127.0.0.1   mysitesname
```

How can i have multiple sites at once? is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Configure [name based virtual hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html), for example

```
# Only needed once.
NameVirtualHost *:80

# One section for each virtual host. Must
# match the "NameVirtualHost" directive.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The FQDN of the host.
    ServerName mysitesname

    # The file system path to the directory with
    # the files to serve by this virtual host.
    DocumentRoot /www/mysitesname
</VirtualHost>
```